# How to get indices of maximum values in numpy but with threshold value?

Tags: python, numpy

My code

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import loadtxt

s = loadtxt("sest.txt", delimiter=" ", unpack=False)
b = loadtxt("base.txt", delimiter=" ", unpack=False)
d=b-s
e = np.absolute(d)
me = e.argsort()[-100:][::-1]
print me
```

I got

```
[400600 401600 399600 400601 401601 399601 401599 400599 399599 399602
 401602 400602 399598 401598 400598 400603 401603 399603 401597 399597
 401604 400597 399604 400604 400605 399605 401605 401596 399596 400596
 399606 401606 400606 399595 401595 400595 399607 401607 400607 400608
 400594 401608 399608 401594 399594 400609 401609 399609 401593 400593
 399593 401610 400610 399610 400592 401592 399592 399611 400611 401611
 399591 401612 401591 400612 400591 399612 399613 401613 400613 399590
 400590 401590 400614 399614 401614 399589 400589 401589 401615 399615
 400615 401616 399616 400616 400588 399588 401588 400617 401617 399617
 401587 400587 399587 400618 399618 401618 399586 400586 401586 400619]
```

Works fine.But I want to specify all elements in d that are larger then 2.5?So I do not care if there are 100 or 200 just everything above this threshold level.Is it possible to extend argsort or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are just seeking array elements above a certain threshold value, you can use x[x>a], where a is the threshold. For purposes of illustration, I will show now using ipython and edit later. Let us assume "x" is some numpy array:

```
  In [9]: x=np.random.rand(1,10)  # an array with random elements

  In [10]: print x[x>0.6]  # select elements above 0.6
    [ 0.71733906  0.74028607  0.66293195  0.86649922  0.7423685   0.71807904
     0.8215429 ]

  In [11]: print x
    [[ 0.36655557  0.71733906  0.74028607  0.66293195  0.86649922  0.21478604
     0.7423685   0.71807904  0.30482062  0.8215429 ]]
```